# Java StackOverflow encapsulation

Tags: java

Trying to set up a `Person class` I have run into a problem trying to encapsulate the information in the class so that it cannot be changed by accident. The class works perfectly fine except for when I try to encapsulate by using setters/getters. The prblem I think is that the methods end up looping eachother until the stack is full.

This is the working code (a cut):

```
// Set this persons father
public void setFather(Person father) {
    // Adding or changing father
    if (father != null && father.isMale()) {
        // If old father, remove as child
        if (this.father != null)
            this.father.removeChild(this);
        this.father = father;
        this.father.children.add(this);  //######//
    }

    // Removing father
    if (father == null) {
        // Removing old father
        if (this.father != null)
            this.father.removeChild(this);
        this.father = null;
    }
}

// Add a child to this person
public void addChild(Person child) {
    // Add child to this persons children if not already a child
    if (!this.children.contains(child)) {
        // Add this person as mother to child if female
        if (this.isFemale()) {
            child.setMother(this);
        }

        // Add this person as father to child if male
        if (this.isMale()) {
            child.setFather(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now notice if I change the line marked with `//#####//` to: `this.father.addChild(this);` I get a stackoverflow.

```
private String name = null;
    private char gender;
    private Person father;
    private Person mother;
    ArrayList<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>(0);
```

I would like children to be private but I don't know how to escape this loop.

This is somewhat homework related but the assignment is done and corrected with a full score, I just want to encapsulate my data.

Comment: In `setFather()` you called `addChild()` and in `addChild()` you called `setFather()` again. This is why you got stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to addChild (from setFather) calls setFather again.

try changing

```
    if (this.isMale()) {
        child.setFather(this);
    }
```

to something along the lines of

```
    if (this.isMale() && child.father != this) {
        child.setFather(this)     
    }
```

This check will break you out of your infinite loop. Just make sure that in your setFather method you set the father **before** calling the setChild method.

Comment: Hmm I wonder if this breaks the class, as it is no child can be fatherless though a person can have null father. That is to say if I add a child to a person object then that child must have this person as parent.